# Enable SSL communication with LDAP server

Tags: database, ssl, ldap, db2, aix

IBMLDAPSecurity.ini file is missing in AIX on location "sqllib/cfg/".

In this directory there is a file IBMLDAPSecurity.ini.sample.

db2 get dbm cfg |grep -i ldap show 0 result.

DB is DB2 v10.5 and server is AIX 7.1.

How I create IBMLDAPSecurity.ini?

Comment: Are you trying to set up LDAP or transparent LDAP? The file is created by copying and then editing it. It is only a sample that needs to be adapted to your environment.

Comment: Our requirement is to enable SSL communication between DB2 instance and the LDAP server. I want to add ENABLE_SSL=TRUE.

Comment: Should I copy IBMLDAPSecurity.ini.sample, rename it to IBMLDAPSecurity.ini and then add ENABLE_SSL=TRUE.

Comment: There is already a section ENABLE_SSL in there, you need to uncomment it. The sample is only a template and shows what options are available.

Comment: Can you please let me know the location of file SSLconfig.ini in DB2 V10.5. I have searched but not found.

Answer (score 0):

SSL not required. 
We have enabled encryption on database level.